# How do I properly freeze a frosted cake?

Tags: cake, freezing

I have a purchased frosted cake I would like to use closer to Christmas. I do not know if it would keep properly in the refrigerator without freezing.  How could I freeze it properly ?  (preferably without damaging the icing, as it is a very expensive cake)

Comment: Both refrigeration and freezing are going to be problematic.  The issue is actually condensation on the cake as it thaws, wetting the icing and ruining it.  You *might* be able to wrap it in plastic wrap after frozen, so that as it thaws there isn't much air near it ... but then you'll have to deal with the possibility of it sticking from what moisture it does get.

Answer (score 3):

You can generally freeze cakes, with our without icing, for a month without problems.  Beyond that, opinions vary...

How to wrap it depends on what type of cake and what type of icing.

For a cake covered in fondant:

- wrap it in plastic wrap (multiple layers if you feel like it, by the time I make sure edges are overlapped I pretty much have two layers)
- then wrap it in aluminum foil (I've never found a good explanation of why you need to do it, but it's what I learned to do...)

For buttercream:

- freeze the iced cake first, then wrap carefully plastic wrap.
- I've never managed to do this without messing up the icing at least a bit.  Work quickly, try not to touch the icing (heat from your hands will soften the icing), use lots of plastic wrap and let it be a bit looser.

In your case:  if "closer to Christmas" means "in a couple weeks" and if the icing is very nice, I wouldn't wrap it.  I'd get either a large enough container or a large plastic bowl that could be placed over the cake and sealed to the plate and just freeze it like that.